# When Should I Add a Dummy Head Node in Algorithm Problems?

Tags: algorithm

Could you please help me understand:

In what types of algorithm problems is it beneficial to add a dummy head node? Particularly, are there specific scenarios or operations where this approach is most useful?
Conversely, in what types of problems should I definitely avoid adding a dummy head node? Are there situations where this would be considered unnecessary or could lead to inefficiency?

I'm exploring the use of dummy head nodes in algorithm problems, specifically for linked list operations. I've tried using them in a few scenarios, expecting they would simplify my code, but sometimes they seem to add complexity instead.

Comment: Hi. Do you have examples of problems where a dummy head node is useful? Where did you hear about these dummy head nodes in the first place?

Comment: You're asking for a list of things, a list that could have no end. This is too broad. Please focus your question on a particular issue. Make it concrete. In general we could say, you would only use a dummy node if it would make the algorithm simpler to implement. In other cases, you better don't. So just compare what the code will look like in both cases (with or without dummy) and choose what best suits you.